# Modal Input Handlers - IInputClickHandler and IInputHandler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a simple holo world scene, with a little `cube` and `cylinder`, as well as the usual suspects: `InputManager`, `HoloLensCamera`, and `CursorWithFeedback`.

I wrote the following simple code (learning from a tutorial) that makes the `cube` disappear when you gaze at it and then air-tap, and then if you gaze at the `cylinder` and air-tap, it will make the cube come back to life.

This all works as expected in the `Unity Editor` but when I connect to the device, the re-appearing part does not respond to air-tap or finger-click on the actual HoloLens.

```
using UnityEngine;
using HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule;

public class Hider : MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler
{
    public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}


using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule;

public class ShowAll : MonoBehaviour, IInputHandler
{
    public List<GameObject> _MyGameObjects;


    public void OnInputUp(InputEventData eventData)
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in _MyGameObjects)
        {
            go.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void OnInputDown(InputEventData eventData)
    {
        // Up is sufficient for 'Click' or 'AirTap' action.
    }
}
```

What am I missing that I cannot get the `OnInputUp` to fire on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to give you an answer ... hope it helps.
I'm a beginner too and I don't have necessary rep for comments, so feel free to ask anything after this =)

As I have understood, you have "Hider" attached to the cube and "ShowAll" attached to the cylinder.
Than you need to populate the public list _MyGameObjects by dragging/dropping the cube in the unity editor.

Since the hiding part works, you could use OnInputClicked for the showing part too, since the cylinder you tap on exists (only the cube appears/disappears).

Note: as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html), even if you setActive(true) a GameObject with a deactivated parent you will NOT see the object on the scene.

Again, hope it helps =)
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are absolutely right. However, I wonder why it all works in `UnityEditor` and not on device? After all, `OnInputUp` and `OnInputDown` also responds to air taps and clicks...

Comment: I made an edit to the call to SetActive(true). Maybe that gives you some error?

Comment: That was a good point, thanks. Having read through the `Input` docs, I am still confused why the tap on cylinder does not work on device. Apparentl, the `IInputClickHandler` specifically handles the tap gesture and the `IInputHandler` handles simple pointer-like inputs, such as taps and clicks, so they are similar, though in the editor, both are done via clicks, which explains why it always works in the editor, but on device, I cannot seem to be able to do tap-click on cylinder to make the cube appear again...

Comment: As you can se [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Scripts/InputEvents) (look at the commit massage) they "Split IInputHandler in two interfaces: IInputHandler, which is for input up/down, and IInputClickHandler, which is for click events (the tap gesture)".

Comment: If you want the cube to reappear by looking at the cylinder and tapping, the fastest way to solve it would be for you to implement IInputClickHandler in ShowAll, the same way you did for hiding. Thought, as is, you should have some kind of reaction too (OnInputUp works like MouseUp). If you want to make it work as is, try getting some console outputs in debug and see if all events are actually triggered...